# JS - How to search in an HTML page that hasn`t been created yet? (Dynamic HTML)

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic, full-text-search, dynamic-html

I have a JSON file with links to html pages in my project folder,
I create the HTML content dynamically in the browser after the user clicks a button.
However, I try to make a search engine in all of these dynamic pages, but can`t think of a way to do it, because the page has not been displayed yet.

Is there any way I can grab the innerHTML of an HTML page in my project folder, and add it to the search engine array?

Thanks a lot,
Cheers

**EDIT:** Forgot to mention that this is a web app, where the user navigates to the final document he needs (each process has child processes, and grandchild processes), so I have alot of content, this is why I am using the JSON and create the content dynamically instead of writing every single html page... (I porbably have about 200 pages)

Comment: How are you storing the pages? You normally can't do that with client side JavaScript.

Comment: I am storing it on a server, the thing is I have alot of content and I try to avoid writing every single page in html, I am building a web app, with processes and sub-processes and sub-sub processes and so on. 
Eventually, I want to make it easier to navigate by creating a search engine in the final documents.

Comment: But how? Do you use Node.js? Otherwise this is not possible with JavaScript alone.

Comment: I accidently hit the enter button and it published my comment before I am done, please read the edited comment

Comment: But how do you get the content from the browser to the server? You need some kind of server side processing to do that and I would use that same server side processing to make your search. Usually this is also done with a database and not as flat files. A database is easier and faster to search.

Comment: I am afraid you don`t understand. I create the dynamic html page by getting the content from the JSON file, which contains links to html pages inside my project folder.
My question is - is there any way to grab the innerHTML of those pages in my project folder without showing it on the browser (I mean the the content has not been created yet, because the content is being created only if the user clicks a button).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get the html with `XMLHttpRequest`. But if you've got a lot of files or a lot of content that would be way too many requests. I would do it server side with nodejs or php or some other server side language.

Comment: The company I am creating this web app to, cannot grant access to PHP servers with sql database, it is a close web. only HTML is supported.

Comment: Well, if you have to do a search function XMLHttpRequest is really the only option. It lets you grab the html and then do whatever you want. But as I said, this will be a lot of requests. I would not do this if this is supposed to go on the internet or many users are expected.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am still looking to see if there is another way I can make it without using server requests.

Comment: As the content resides on the server this is impossible to do without server requests. Only if you include everything in one giant html file.

Comment: I actually read more about XMLHttpRequests and managed to do it with AJAX.